# Disable wrapping for some lines but not others

Tags: cocoa

I have a NSTextView subclass. It displays normal text (which should wrap, ideally around the 80-char line) and ascii style tables (which should *not* be wrapped).

Mockup:

[image: Mockup]

As you see the text on top is wrapped, while the table extends.

I have code that figures out if a line is a table, but I need some ideas on how to go with the selective (non)wrapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use multiple text containers with your layout manager.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextSystemArchitecture/ArchitectureOverview.html)

"This one is the width of the text view (it wraps); the next one is as wide as it needs to be (doesn't wrap); etc."